# Bug report: Review queue count discrepancy

Tags: bug

See below: the header indicates that there are three posts available for me to review, but when I click on it, everything is zero.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This has been an issue for over a year, i'm afraid.  The dev team is aware of it, but it is one of those things they have never tracked down and fixed. They are chronically understaffed, it takes them a long time to get to small issues.

Comment: Fair enough.  I noticed that it eventually self-resolved.

Comment: @kimholder et al. I've assumed that at least when it *does not* appear, there *aren't* any in the queue. I'll keep an eye on it.

Comment: @uhoh Can confirm that there can be items in the queue when the header flag does not indicate such. (Header flag didn't show, but there were two items for me just now.)

Comment: @Tristan Wow, thanks for the info! OK. right now mine says 8, but there are zero for me when I go there.

Comment: The notification is heavily cached, which means [it shows all the pending tasks anyone might see](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230742/notification-for-reviews-shows-way-too-many) and doesn't update very frequently.

Comment: That makes sense for why that would happen.  One would think the caching severely limits its utility though...