# What prevents me from seeing this close vote in review?

Tags: discussion, support

I understand that the review queues [sometimes generate numbers](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/844/12102) of items to be reviewed up in the "dashboard area" that are false.

This case is the opposite, a [question with a close vote](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21256/12102), but I don't see any flags in the top of my display, and the queues show all zeros.

[I've read](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/844/#comment3387_844) even if there are items in the queue, sometimes the dashboard will not reflect it, but this time I see all zeros.

Why?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**My understanding of the queue mechanics:**

This question showed up for me in the queues some hours ago. As I am a moderator, any item in the queues I handle is dismissed from the queue.

This means that as I chose "leave open", the question is no longer in the queue and did not become closed. However, the close vote does not get deleted, it stays with the post.

If any other person casts a second close vote, the question is back in the queue, this time with two votes to close.

Comment: That's interesting! It would be cool if one could hover ones mouse over all those buttons and a short, clear, functional description would appear. I still am not sure I know the difference between `Skip` and `I'm done`. Skip the queue or skip the question, I'm done with the queue or I'm done with the question or I'm done with review. Is Skip like a "cancel" that does not save actions, whereas 'I'm done" keeps the changes? Anyway, those are rhetorical questions, no need to answer here. But the hover-over explanations would be great!

Comment: @uhoh That's probably better as a separate question, but in review queues, *Skip* means "I don't know what to do with this question, so I don't want to do anything" and *I'm Done* (which requires you to take at least one action on the post) means "I have done everything I feel is necessary on this post".

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Thanks, but I'm not really asking for an answer as much as I am trying to illustrate how the hover-reveal option might be useful. It's meant to be rhetorical - pointing out that the single word labels might have some ambiguity. I'm not passionate enough about it though to write a feature request.