# Is the SXSE review queue (and new reputation indicator) now broken?

Tags: support, bug

With the old header, the review queue flags were active and [often overstated](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/844/12102) what was currently in need of attention for a given user.

Since the new header, I've now *never seen* a notice of things in need of review, even when aware that there were items that should have been. In other SE sites I see the red circle (shown below) but never here.

[image]

When I clicked the review queue icon and select `all queues`, I see that there is an item for me. Shouldn't I see a red dot when logged into SXSE?

[image]

If it turns out to be a bug report, we can add the tag. right now just looking for assistance understanding the behavior.

Comment: I did not even know it is supposed to show a red dot :) Yup, this looks broken.

Comment: @Hohmannfan I have a red dot now! It correctly took me to open items in the review queue. Fixed?

Comment: @Hohmannfan no, it's still broken. After that one dot, I'm not getting any indication. I believe that I'm missing some other notifications as well, but can't be sure yet. Is someone working on this, or should I escalate to stackexchange meta myself?

Comment: I do get the green numbers, but I haven't seen the dot. I've only seen the dot on askubuntu.

Comment: @OrganicMarble see all the comments below [I'm not seeing review queue notifications (red dot) or +5's or +10's for reputation in Space SE - how to further investigate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303424/303080) It looks like all mysteries are solved. Thanks for the reminder. I'm hoping someone posts an answer here, and there now. If it doesn't happen, then I will.

Comment: That algorithm is...complicated.  I'll just look for the dots, lol.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Algorithms will take over the world unless the Elon Musks protect of from the Mark Zuckerbergs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new navigation bar comes a new algorithm. The current behavior is outlined in this [question which is also its own answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226/303080).

The idea seems to be that you need to visit the review queue, or at least click the icon in the navigation bar and look for gray dots to see if there are items you can review.

The red dot only appears on the navigation bar if the quantity of work needing to be done is beyond an algorithmically determined amount.

For further clarification, see the link.